# Mod rewrite only numeric query strings

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a user visits `/user` he will see his own profile, but when he visits `/user/[id]` he will see the user's profile with the specified `id`. However, somebody could also type `/user/[random string]` which leads into a `500 error` on my server. So I want to redirect any  `non-numeric` request to a `404 page`.

Here are my `RewriteRule`s

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/edit /edit.php
# RewriteRule ^errors/404.html /user.php?id=$([\w])
RewriteRule ^user/([\d])$ /user.php?id=$1
```

If the second one is commented or not, it doesn't matter, any `non-numeric` `query string` will produce a `500 error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your rule adding a plus:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([\d]+)$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/.+$ /errors/500.html [L]
```

or:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ /user.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/.+$ /errors/500.html [L]
```

The [L] modifier stops parsing, is the reason what error 500 rule must place after first rule.

Comment: I modify and test the rules